# ESP32 Rebooting while converting String to Hex Array

Tags: esp32, error

I wrote [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ImK6y2eZ9eO5znS2TJ3GHKRzaxjviwI/view?usp=sharing) code to convert String to Hex Array.

```
const char* hexstring = "0x21 0x73 0x10 0xfa 0x7a 0x00 0xff .../*40995 character long string*/....0xaa"    
void setup() {
    char* temp;
    //Serial.printf("%s",hexstring);
    unsigned int number[8199];
    
    number[0] = strtoul (hexstring,&temp,16);
    for(int i=1;i<8199;i++)
     number[i]= (int)strtoul(temp, &temp, 16);
    
    for(int i=0;i<8199;i++)
        {
            if(i%64)
                printf("\n");
            printf("%d, ",number[i]);
        }
}

void loop(){
}
```

But it is causing ESP32 to reboot.
[image]

Could anyone help me with the reason why?

Comment: I don't quite understand, what you are trying to do with your code. It doesn't make much sense to me. First: Why are you providing `&temp` to `strtoul()`? temp is an uninitialized pointer

Comment: Why do you write to `number[0]` two times instead of using `number[i]`? Why is that for loop only 5 iterations long, while the other, which does not write to number is 8199 iterations long? All in all I'm not sure how to help here other than pointing these things out. Maybe describe, what you are trying to do

Comment: @chrisl I corrected it, it was supposed to be `number[i]`, after searching a bit I found a way to convert a string of hex values into array of hex values. So I have tried it in C online compiler it works fine. 
Eg `const char* hexstring = "0x21 0x49...` becomes `unsigned int number[8199]=[33, 73...`

Comment: My bad, I edited the code to try a shorter string, and mistakenly copied that one. I corrected it now. Iteration is 8199

Comment: Still, why do you use `temp` uninitialized? At that position the parameter is the end pointer (pointer to where the conversion should stop). Null pointer here means conversion until end of string. So this comes down to if `temp` gets implicitly initialized to the null pointer. Might be the case for your online compiler. Please try using `NULL` instead of `temp` gor `strtoul()`

Comment: @chrisl, _"where the conversion should stop"_  It's actually used as at _output_ not input. It doesn't tell `strtoul` where to stop lexing, it gives `strtoul` a means to tell the caller where it _did_ stop. So you can use it to figure out where to resume your next operation, which is what they're doing. If you give it `NULL` you're just saying "I don't care where" you stopped. If you give it a pointer to a character pointer, you're saying "I do care where you stopped, tell me with this pointer that I'm pointing you at."

Comment: @timemage Ah, ok, then I guess I understood that wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
void setup() {
    char* temp;
    //Serial.printf("%s",hexstring);
    unsigned int number[8199]; <----- too much.
```

So, you're trying to put a 32796 byte object on the stack. I don't know exactly why you're seeing the manifestation that you are, but I'm not surprised.

I just took an ESP32-CAM and started playing with different sizes and found that around 1800 (`unsigned int`s) is where things start to go sideways, failing occasionally rather than constantly.  By a 2000 count, it continually reboots with `rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)` transitioning to `rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)`   and later to very roughly around 5000 it becomes `rst:0x8 (TG1WDT_SYS_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)`

I *may* fill out some details later if I look into it deeper. The ESP32 and SDK is complicated enough that there may well be a function can call that will permit a higher stack level. But this is mostly to satisfy curiosity.

Putting very large things (relative to the system size) on the stack is usually not done. I hesitate to try to tell you what exactly you should do; it wouldn't surprise me if you don't need this array at all for what you ultimately want to do, but that's a *different* question). So, I'll just say get it off the stack through either dynamic memory allocation (e.g. through `new` or `malloc`), possibly using a smart pointer (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`) to manage that since those are available on the ESP32, or perhaps just making the variable either a `static` local or global. Or again if possible finding out why you might not need this array.

#### Simple minimal change

So, I'm not going to tell you that this is a good idea, but a minimal change would be to `static` qualify this as `static unsigned int number[8199];` Then you won't get that reset cause, here, for this reason.

---

#### Some details for anyone curious

If you want to see some of the guts, you look in the ESP32 core for Arduino where it [creates the task](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/2.0.5/cores/esp32/main.cpp#L71) that [ultimately runs `setup()`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/2.0.5/cores/esp32/main.cpp#L42) for you. You can see that it calls [`getArduinoLoopTaskStackSize()`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/2.0.5/cores/esp32/main.cpp#L36-L38) returning [`ARDUINO_LOOP_STACK_SIZE`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/2.0.5/cores/esp32/main.cpp#L14) which by default is `8192`. 8192 **bytes,** not `unsigned int`s. With `sizeof(unsigned int)` being 4, this is *very roughly* in the vicinity of the 1800 `unsigned int`s where things started to fall apart in my testing above. Rather than chase down the configurion I just made a sketch that does `Serial.println(getArduinoLoopTaskStackSize());` and yeah, it prints 8192.

`getArduinoLoopTaskStackSize` is a [weakly defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) function which would allow something to redefine in elsewhere in the program to overload the default one. So, just out of curiosity I wrote one as follows:

```cpp
size_t getArduinoLoopTaskStackSize(void) {
  size_t r_size = sizeof(unsigned int [8199]); // exactly the size your array
  r_size += r_size >> 3; // add about 1/8 (or 12.5%) extra 
  return r_size;
}
```

It no longer crashes. Should you do this? Probably not. But, if you ever have a legitimate reason to put a 32K array on the stack on an ESP32 it *may* be an option. I mostly just did this to see what would happen. It's barely been tested.